# Symfony gedmo tree + translatable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, tree

After having problems on configuring gedmo libraries i've solved it switching to stofdoctrineextensionbundle.

Here my entity: http://pastebin.com/8nXrLsTh

I was following official documentation to do some test on the various doctrine extension.

Edit config file:

```
config.yml:
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

        mappings:
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_translator:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslator # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_loggable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoLoggable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mappingmapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_tree:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTree # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
```

Now i create a test menu tree, just to understand its functions:

```
/**
 * @Route("/createtestmenu")
 */
public function createtestmenuAction() {
    $food = new Menu();
    $food->setTitle('cereali');
    $food->setTranslatableLocale('it_IT');

    $fruits = new Menu();
    $fruits->setTitle('grano');
    $fruits->setParent($food);
    $fruits->setTranslatableLocale('it_IT');

    $vegetables = new Menu();
    $vegetables->setTitle('farro');
    $vegetables->setParent($food);
    $vegetables->setTranslatableLocale('it_IT');

    $carrots = new Menu();
    $carrots->setTitle('avena');
    $carrots->setParent($vegetables);
    $carrots->setTranslatableLocale('it_IT');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($food);
    $em->persist($fruits);
    $em->persist($vegetables);
    $em->persist($carrots);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('creato menu');
}
```

After this i've create the tree translatable translation. I've translated almost everything except 1 node to understand the translatable fallback.

```
/**
 * @Route("/traducimenu")
 */
public function traducimenuAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $cereali = $em->find('AppBundle:Menu', 13);
    $cereali->setTitle("Cereals");
    $cereali->setTranslatableLocale('en_GB'); // change locale
    $em->persist($cereali);
    $em->flush();

    $grano = $em->find('AppBundle:Menu', 14);
    $grano->setTitle("wheat");
    $grano->setTranslatableLocale('en_GB'); // change locale
    $em->persist($grano);
    $em->flush();

    $farro = $em->find('AppBundle:Menu', 15);
    $farro->setTitle("spelt");
    $farro->setTranslatableLocale('en_GB'); // change locale
    $em->persist($farro);
    $em->flush();

    /* $farro = $em->find('AppBundle:Menu', 11);
       $farro->setTitle("spelt");
       $farro->setTranslatableLocale('en_GB'); // change locale
       $em->persist($farro);
       $em->flush(); */

    return new Response('traduzione creata');
}
```

Now I generate the tree with base language, but I can't retrieve the translated tree, actually I can retrieve only one node.

```
/**
 * @Route("/menu")
 */
public function readmenuAction() {

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Menu');
$options = array(
    'decorate' => true,
    'rootOpen' => '<ul>',
    'rootClose' => '</ul>',
    'childOpen' => '<li>',
    'childClose' => '</li>',
    /*'nodeDecorator' => function($node) {
        return '<a href="/page/' . $node['slug'] . '">' . $node[$field].'</a>';
    }*/
);

$em2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$node = $em2->find('AppBundle:Menu', 13);
$node->setTranslatableLocale('en_GB');
$em2->refresh($node);

/**
 * translation dump
 */
dump($node);

$htmlTree = $em->childrenHierarchy(
        $node, /* starting from root nodes */
        false, /* false: load all children, true: only direct */
        $options,
        true
);

dump($htmlTree);
return $this->render('AppBundle:menu:menutest.html.twig', array(
            'menutest' => $htmlTree,
                )
);
```

}

If I get one single node i'm able to get base language and translation but unfortunately I do not understand how to get a complete translated tree. How can i do it?? Unfortunately the official documentation is very poor, if someone can give me some input to start studying from...Thank you S.